# Regex Start of String to a number

Tags: c#, regex

I've been reading regex guide and tutorials for a few days now, but I still have no idea how to write a solution for my problem.

I need to extract a string from the following..

```
The quick brown fox 123 jumps over the lazy dog.
```

returns

```
123 jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Basically from the start of the string to a number and then the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Regex.Replace`,

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, @"^\D*(\d+.*)$", "$1");
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nW0mT4/2)

`^` Asserts that we are at the start. `\D*` matches zero or more non-digit characters, so `^\D*` matches all the charcaters from the start upto the first number. `(\d+.*)` captures the following number along with the following characters upto the last. Replacing the whole match with the characters inside group index 1 will give you the desired output.

For the sake of simplicity you could also use,

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, @"^\D*", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match a digit (`\d`) and then match multiple anythings (`.*`) until the end of string (`$`), something simple like

```
\d.*$
```

should work.
Getting the right regex for your needs, usually is a process of trial and error, so test whatever regex your using first - [Here](http://regex101.com/r/mY4dO0/1) for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^\d]+
```

You can also use `replace`.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vX2wN5/2